How to check the program executor permissions on a certain path
os.access() doesn't work as expected; it always returns True.
I found this method to verify if I have permission to read a file or directory, which should also imply that I have permission to check the path’s permissions.
def _readable_path(abs_path: Path, uname: str):
    # Existing validation
    try:
        exists = abs_path.exists()
    except PermissionError as e:
        return build_not_path_access(abs_path, uname, e)
    except Exception as e:
        return build_general_path_access(abs_path, uname, e)

    if not exists:
        return build_file_not_found(abs_path)

    # Reading perm check
    try:
        security_descriptor = win32security.GetFileSecurity(
            str(abs_path), win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION
        )
    except win32security.error as e:
        if e.winerror == 5:  # Not reading perms
            return False
        return build_general_path_access(abs_path, uname, e)

    return True

Is there a library that simplifies path permission validation on Windows in a way similar to how os.access() works on Linux?

are you sure, it returns True? it's false here: os.path.exists on c:\hiberfil.sys returns True --- os.path.isfile on c:\hiberfil.sys returns True ---
os.path.isdir on c:\hiberfil.sys returns False ---
os.F_OK on c:\hiberfil.sys returns False ---
os.R_OK on c:\hiberfil.sys returns False ---
os.W_OK on c:\hiberfil.sys returns False ---
os.X_OK on c:\hiberfil.sys returns False

@todeskurve Yes, I'm pretty sure that os.access() always return True.
# ...
path = Path("C:/backups")
print(f"path exists?: {path.exists()}")
print(f"r (perm): {os.access(path, os.R_OK)}")
print(f"w (perm): {os.access(path, os.W_OK)}")
print(f"x (perm): {os.access(path, os.X_OK)}")
inner = path / "inner.txt"
try:
    inner.touch()
except PermissionError:
    print(f"PermissionError was raised")

path exists?: True
r (perm): True
w (perm): True
x (perm): True
PermissionError was raised

no, it doesn't, try Path("c:\hiberfil.sys")! but i must agree, these might be corner cases :-D
